# How to get screen shoots from ios simulator in my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, macos-carbon

if ios simulator is active,

how to send any message to ios simulator got screen shoot and stored in clipboard (have shortcut in ios simulator)

and i get from clipboard this screen shoot

in short, how to get screen shoot from ios simulator with objective-c

i need more objective c recources for communication between mac os apps,

Thanks

Comment: you need to take a screenshot programmatically ???

Comment: Programmatically from iOS App, oder OSX App? From the App that runs in the Simulator?

Comment: yes i need get screenshoot with my osx app (programatically) from ios simulator (maybe osx have similar windows api, i dont know this)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Screen capture for iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253204/screen-capture-for-ios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
       [super viewDidLoad];
       UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
       [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
       UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
       UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
       NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
       NSArray *arrPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *filePath = [[arrPath objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.png"];
       NSLog(@"%@",filePath);
      [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Press **cmd + shift + 4** to select the area for screenshot or press **cmd + shift+ 4 + space** to get the screenshot of the simulator window as a whole

Comment: These screenshots will be saved on your desktop

Comment: You can also press cmd+ctrl+c in the simulator to copy only the screenshot (without the window border) to the clipboard.