# Screen capture for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

i m using this codes for screen capture for iOS:

```
CGImageRef screen = UIGetScreenImage();
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:screen];
CGImageRelease(screen);  
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
CGRect screenshotFrame;  
CGImageRef screenshotRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(screenshotRef, screenshotFrame);
UIImage * screenshot = [[(UIImage *)screenshotRef retain] autorelease];
CGImageRelease(screenshotRef);
```

But my screen contain tool bar bottom of the screen.i don't want tool bar on my captured screen. How can i crop tool bar ? How can i modified my code ?

Comment: Similar question is already marked as solved. here is link to your solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687909/ios-screenshot-part-of-the-screen

Answer (score 2):

I think you can capture the layer of self.view because it the root view

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
    //Retina display
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
} else {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
}
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(/*CGRECT*/);     
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *screenImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Here in `CGRect` pass your rect which you want to take screenshot.

Hope it helps you..

Answer (score 0):

Set your

```
CGRect screenshotFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 436);
// 480(screen height) - 44(toolbar height) = 436
```